# AWS Glue: crawler misinterprets timestamps as strings. GLUE ETL meant to convert strings to timestamps makes them NULL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have been playing around with **AWS Glue** for some quick analytics by following the tutorial 
[here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-data-lake-foundation-with-aws-glue-and-amazon-s3/)

While I have been able to successfully create crawlers and discover data in Athena, I've had issues with the data types created by the crawler. The `date` and `timestamp` data types get read as `string` data types.

I followed this up by creating an `ETL` job in GLUE using the data source created by the crawler as the input and a target table in **Amazon S3**

As part of the mapping transformation, I converted the data types of the date and timestamp as `string` to `timestamp` but unfortunately the ETL converted these column types to `NULLS`. I have contemplated using classifiers with `GROK` expressions but then decided transform them as part of ETL in GLUE.

The timestamp format is as `1/08/2010  6:15:00 PM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the format of timestamp you use therefore I assumed that the format is the following:

```
2018-05-30T12:22:07.000Z
```

In this case you can set  the serde parameter in the table definition as below:

```
'timestamp.formats'='yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'
```

Comment: Sorry, just updated my post. I am not 100% sure if there is anyway to include this in a GLUE crawler though.

Comment: I mean in the table definition in Athena, not in Glue Crawler.
For your format you should use  'timestamp.formats'='d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss a'

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `example`(
  `col0` string, 
  `col1` string, 
  `col2` timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://example'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'delimiter'='\;', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'timestamp.formats'='d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss a', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1535632231', 
  'typeOfData'='file')

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create an external table in Athena directly using the right timestamp format. But I guess the question is how to have the crawler identify appropriate `data types` and make the results available for analytics in Athena. Whether using grok expression or have the ETL job for data transformation.

Comment: @BalajeeAddanki  ,In the Tables: I set the :'timestamp.formats'='d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a' with my data looks exact the same as :1/08/2010  6:15:00 PM, however, when I set this column as timestamp, and query it in Aethan, it showed the error like :  IVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '1/08/2010 6:15:00 PM' for field 0: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]  . so are you settting this column as string or timestamp in the table ?

Answer (score 6):

Following are the built-in classifiers for the timestamp data. As you can see the data you have does not match any of them. You will need to create a custom classifier and then add that to a new Crawler (updating existing crawler does not work)

```
 TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?

 TZ (?:[PMCE][SD]T|UTC)

 DATESTAMP_RFC822 %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{TZ}

 DATESTAMP_RFC2822 %{DAY}, %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}

 DATESTAMP_OTHER %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{TZ} %{YEAR}

 DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG %{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM2}%{MONTHDAY}%{HOUR}%{MINUTE}%{SECOND}

 CISCOTIMESTAMP %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}
```

Comment: The complete list of built-in patterns: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#classifier-builtin-patterns